# Set up Kubernetes using Ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubeadm

I am setting up a Kubernetes setup using Ansible. To set up master I have written a playbook as shown below.

```
- hosts: master
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: initialize the cluster
      shell: kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 

    - name: create .kube directory
      become: yes
      become_user: ubuntu
      file:
        path: $HOME/.kube
        state: directory
        mode: 0755

    - name: copy admin.conf to user's kube config
      copy:
        src: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
        dest: /home/ubuntu/.kube/config
        remote_src: yes
        owner: ubuntu

    - name: install Pod network
      become: yes
      become_user: ubuntu
      shell: kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/a70459be0084506e4ec919aa1c114638878db11b/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml >> pod_network_setup.txt
      args:
        chdir: $HOME
        creates: pod_network_setup.txt
```

The problem is that when i run the playbook, it doesn't wait for the initialization to complete i.e. for command "kubeadm init " to return and runs each task one after another. Since, the initialization takes time and one it is completed then only the file "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf" is created. As Ansible doesn't wait for it to complete it exists giving error in task 3 that "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf" is not found.

If I run following playbook then Ansible waits till the initialization is complete i.e. the control hangs till "kubeadm init " returns.

```
- hosts: master
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: initialize the cluster
      shell: kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

How can I make Ansible wait for command "kubeadm init " to complete and then only start another command ?

Answer (score 8):

There are three ways:

1. [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html) some time after executing `kubeadm init` ansible task.

```
- hosts: master
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: initialize the cluster
      shell: kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 
    - name: sleep for 20 seconds
      wait_for:
        timeout: 20
```

2. Make use of [until](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) in ansible.

```
- hosts: master
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: initialize the cluster
      shell: kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
      register: result
      until: result.stdout.find("Your Kubernetes master has initialized successfully!") != -1
      retries: 1
      delay: 20
```

***NOTE:** Here we retry `kubeadm init` until we get the string `Your Kubernetes master has initialized successfully!` in the output.*

3. Check if the file `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` exists after executing `kubeadm init` ansible task.

```
- hosts: master
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: initialize the cluster
      shell: kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
    - name: create .kube directory
      become: yes
      become_user: ubuntu
      file:
        path: $HOME/.kube
        state: directory
        mode: 0755
    - name: Check admin.conf file exists.
      stat:
        path: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
      register: k8s_conf
    - name: copy admin.conf to user's kube config
      copy:
        src: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
        dest: /home/ubuntu/.kube/config
        remote_src: yes
        owner: ubuntu
      when: k8s_conf.stat.exists
```

***NOTE:** Here we execute admin.conf copy only when the k8s config file `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` exists.*

Answer (score 1):

When I use command module instead of shell module it appears to wait as it has no trouble making the copy of admin.conf. Also my next step after creating the .kube/config is to apply flannel overlay and that also works. Here's what my tasks looks like.

```
  - name: Initialize the Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm
    command: kubeadm init --config /etc/kubernetes/kubeadminit.yaml

  - name: create .kube in root home
    file:
      path: /root/.kube
      state: directory

  - name: copy kubernetes admin.conf to root home dir
    copy:
      src: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
      dest: /root/.kube/config
      remote_src: yes
```